# Standard Matrix Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the standard matrix for the following composition in $\mathbb{R^2}$:
>
> A reflection about the $x$-axis followed by a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{6}$

In my test, I answered the following, but got it wrong:

\begin{align}&T:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2} \text{is given by:} \\ &\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}&-\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}} \\ \sin{\frac{\pi}{6}} & \cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}\end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} &-\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

My guess, is that I had the matrices in the incorrect order - am I correct in saying that was my mistake?

The reason why I assume that was my mistake, is if I carefully reread the question:
$$T_A(x,y)=(x,-y) $$
$$T_B(x,y)=(x\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}} -y\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}, x\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}+y\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}})$$

Thus I must have $T_B(T_A(\textbf{x}))=[T_B][T_A].$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Your mistake is that you multiplied the matrices in the wrong order.